# Making an image for each line of a mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I have this (I'm going to add more once it works, but I wanted to keep it simple for testing)

```
    <?php
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host= info goes here');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from table_name') as $row) {
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('cert.jpg');
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
  $font_path = 'arial.TTF';
  $text = $row['fname'];
  $font_size = 25;
  imagettftext($jpg_image, $font_size, 0, 500, 100, $white, $font_path, $text);
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

The code works, but it is only taking the first name, I'm wondering if there is a way to make it so that it will make one for each name (line) until it reaches the end of the row.
I'm planning on saving one image per name. I'm trying to make something that fills in information on a certificate and saves each one in a folder on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make an unique filename for it everytime, e.g. based on some field in the database, a timestamp or a random number and pass it to imagejpeg. See [the manual about the function](http://php.net/imagejpeg)

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image, "some/dir/some_unique_filename.jpeg");
```